# Correcting error with toJpeg in ElectronJS

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have problem with this block of code.

```
ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("videoScreen"), 0, 0);
imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height).data;
if (sendFullScreenshot || lastFrame == undefined) {
    sendFullScreenshot = false;
    croppedFrame = new Blob([electron.nativeImage.createFromDataURL(ctx.canvas.toDataURL()).toJpeg(100), new Uint8Array(6)]);
}
```

The error is:

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1c3a.png)

Can someone help me?

Comment: fix method name from `toJpeg` to `toJPEG`, docs here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#imagetojpegquality

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your error message is telling you whats wrong! The correct method name is toJPEG() as per the documentation here https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#native-imagetojpeg

Comment: Thank you @bcperth , you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no method: `.toJpeg`

if You check [manual](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#imagetojpegquality) You'll see that it's `toJPEG`

> image.toJPEG(quality)
>
> - quality Integer (required) - Between 0 - 100.
>
> Returns Buffer - A Buffer that contains the image's JPEG encoded data.

So fix:

```
croppedFrame = new Blob([
  electron.nativeImage
          .createFromDataURL(ctx.canvas.toDataURL())
          .toJPEG(100), 
  new Uint8Array(6)
]);
```